# How to solve violation of primary key cannot insert duplicate values error in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key, sql-insert

I  executed the following query to my `Order Details` table which is intended to copy all records from `OrderDetai11`

```
insert into [dbo].[Order Details] (OrderID,ProductID,UnitPrice,Quantity,Discount) 
select OrderID,ProductID,UnitPrice,Quantity,Discount 
from[dbo].[Order Detai11] as OD1 
where OD1. OrderID between 1 and 150000;
```

I have received the following error

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 1 Violation of PRIMARY KEY
>   constraint 'PK_Order_Details'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object
>   'dbo.Order Details'. The duplicate key value is (10248, 11). The
>   statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming [Order Details] is a copy of [Order Detail11]. You just want to insert or update your records: you can use a MERGE ([what is a MERGE? here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)), example :

```
MERGE [dbo].[Order Details]
USING ( select OrderID,ProductID,UnitPrice,Quantity,Discount 
        from[dbo].[Order Detai11]
        where OrderID between 1 and 150000 
    ) As tblMergeDetail(OrderID,ProductID,UnitPrice,Quantity,Discount)
ON (    tblMergeDetail.OrderId = [dbo].[Order Details].OrderId  )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
SET ProductID = tblMergeDetail.ProductID,
    UnitPrice = tblMergeDetail.UnitPrice,
    Quantity = tblMergeDetail.Quantity,
    Discount = tblMergeDetail.Discount
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (OrderID,ProductID,UnitPrice,Quantity,Discount)
VALUES (
    tblMergeDetail.OrderID,
    tblMergeDetail.ProductID,
    tblMergeDetail.UnitPrice,
    tblMergeDetail.Quantity,
    tblMergeDetail.Discount
);
```

If you want to copy only none existent record you can just exclude the values inside [Order Details], example :

```
insert into [dbo].[Order Details] 
(OrderID,ProductID,UnitPrice,Quantity,Discount) 
select OrderID,ProductID,UnitPrice,Quantity,Discount
from[dbo].[Order Detai11] as OD1 
where OD1.OrderID between 1 and 150000
and NOT EXISTS (    select  exclusionTbl.OrderID
                    from    [dbo].[Order Details] exclusionTbl
                    where   exclusionTbl.OrderID = OD1.OrderID
                )
```

EDIT :

An other example:

```
insert into [dbo].[Order Details] 
(OrderID,ProductID,UnitPrice,Quantity,Discount) 
select OrderID,ProductID,UnitPrice,Quantity,Discount
from[dbo].[Order Detai11] as OD1 
where OD1.OrderID between 1 and 150000
  and OD1.OrderID NOT IN(   select  exclusionTbl.OrderID
                            from    [dbo].[Order Details] exclusionTbl
                            where   exclusionTbl.OrderID between 1 and 150000
                        )
```

For the NOT EXISTS query: We check that it doesn't exist an OrderID inside [Order Details] that we want to insert from [OrderDetai11]

For the NOT IN query: We check from all [OrderDetai11].OrderIDs nobody is contained in the list of [Order Details].OrderID. It achieve the same result as NOT EXISTS query.

Comment: Nailed it .. Its fine here .. Can u explain me the NOT exists part in second query

Comment: [At first you need to know what a PRIMARY KEY is.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179610.aspx)
If you did understand that, you know now why you get your error : "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint ". My condition in the 2nd query is to never trigger a duplication of your key (OrderID).

Comment: Arg I just realized that I assumed that OrderID is your Primary Key. Is that correct? Otherwise I'm totally wrong with both of my answers.

Comment: YES . Primary key is the OrderID and merge is something which i will look into it.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't that clear but MERGE solution is different from the 2 others since it would update your previous records. (Also can be used for deleting rather than updating.) And the others 2 will just add line that doesn't exist in [Order Details]. Pick the one that suits your need best.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to insert records with the same primary key into the new table.

You need to make sure that the original table does not have duplicates records, presumably your primary key is `OrderID`.

You can check this by using this select query on your original table:

```
SELECT OrderID, COUNT(OrderID) AS Total
FROM [dbo].[Order Detai11] 
GROUP BY OrderID
ORDER BY Total DESC
```

If there are any rows with 2 or more in the `total` column, then you have duplicates.

You either need to remove the duplicates, or if you want to keep them, you need to create a new column in your new table and make this your primary key.

**After comments:**

Your original table probably does not have a primary key, or if it does, you've not copied it correctly to the new table.

There is no way this is going to work unless you do one of the following:

- Create a new column and make that the primary key.
- Use a composite primary key (a primary key made up of more than one column).
- Remove the `OrderID` as the primary key.

Comment: Most of the columns has duplicates and i need to insert all of them and besides i have column name is same for both tables

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure the destination table doesn't have duplicates. And if the source table has duplicates, make sure you fetch only distinct records.

```
/******  REMOVE DUPLICATES ******/

 WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT *,
       RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY OrderId ORDER BY OrderId)
   FROM [dbo].[Order Details]
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1

/****** Script for merging after removing duplicates from destination table  ******/

BEGIN
WITH dedupe AS (SELECT DISTINCT OrderID,ProductID,UnitPrice,Quantity,Discount 
from[dbo].[Order Detai11])
MERGE [dbo].[Order Details]
USING dedupe AS tblMergeDetail
ON (    tblMergeDetail.OrderId = [dbo].[Order Details].OrderId  )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
SET ProductID = tblMergeDetail.ProductID,
    UnitPrice = tblMergeDetail.UnitPrice,
    Quantity = tblMergeDetail.Quantity,
    Discount = tblMergeDetail.Discount
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (OrderID,ProductID,UnitPrice,Quantity,Discount)
VALUES (
    tblMergeDetail.OrderID,
    tblMergeDetail.ProductID,
    tblMergeDetail.UnitPrice,
    tblMergeDetail.Quantity,
    tblMergeDetail.Discount
);
```